# Python replace value in dictionary (set in class object) fails: TypeError: 'annotation' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary

I'm creating an object to pass into another function:

```
class annotation():
    def __init__(self, *kwargs):
       self.annotation = {'x': 1, 
                        'y': None, 
                        'showarrow': False, 
                        'text': None, 
                        'bordercolor': 'Black', 
                        'borderwidth': 1, 
                        }
```

I assign the object properties as follows:

```
spec.annotation = vs.annotation(spec)
```

and then change the `y` value:

```
spec.annotation['y'] = 1
```

When I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'annotation' object does not support item assignment

What am I doing wrong? I changed the default value of `y` from `None` to `1` in the class, but got the same error.

Thanks

Comment: when you are using the annotation()  you are creating a new object you are not assigning the self.annotation of the existing object you can assign it without the ()

Comment: That was a silly mistake. Thanks. I've fixed. But I still get the same error. FYI, in my code above I added spec in the brackets. But I also tried it your way by removing the () completely.

Comment: Also when I just run the code snippet and then type spec.annotation['x'], I get the same error.

Comment: In your example, you can assign by spec.annotation.annotation['y'] = 1 since the annotation class has an annotation attribute. It will be best practice not to use the same word for the class name and hs attribute and class name in python mainly start with an uppercase character.